# Display HTML page in browser window upon clicking a button

Tags: html, apache-flex, air

I have a button on flex(AIR app). when i click on the button,has to open a browser window which will display an HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [`URLRequest`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) to the web page, and open it with [`navigateToURL`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29) :

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com/");
navigateToURL(urlRequest);
```

Example loading a page upon click of a button with Flex MXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.net.navigateToURL;

            protected function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com"), "_blank");
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button label="Open page"
              click="clickHandler(event)" />

</s:Application>
```

[navigateToURL()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29):

> Opens or replaces a window in the application that contains the Flash
>   Player container (usually a browser). In Adobe AIR, the function opens
>   a URL in the default system web browser.
>
> #### *Parameters*
>
> `request:URLRequest` — A URLRequest object that specifies the URL to navigate to.
>   For content running in Adobe AIR, when using the navigateToURL()
>   function, the runtime treats a URLRequest that uses the POST method
>   (one that has its method property set to URLRequestMethod.POST) as
>   using the GET method.
>
> `window:String` (default = null) — The browser window or HTML frame in
>   which to display the document indicated by the request parameter. You
>   can enter the name of a specific window or use one of the following
>   values:
>
> - "_self" specifies the current frame in the current window.
> - "_blank" specifies a new window.
> - "_parent" specifies the parent of the current frame.
> - "_top" specifies the top-level frame in the current window.

[urlRequest()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html):

> Creates a URLRequest object. If System.useCodePage is true, the
>   request is encoded using the system code page, rather than Unicode. If
>   System.useCodePage is false, the request is encoded using Unicode,
>   rather than the system code page.
>
> #### *Parameters*
>
> `url:String` (default = null) — The URL to be requested. You
>   can set the URL later by using the url property.

Comment: how can i specify the size of browser window to be opend?

Comment: When embedded in a webpage, you could use `ExternalInterface` from the html container.  From AIR, perhaps you could `new URLRequest("javascript:window.open(...); void(0);");`?